# Reference Session in Helper class

Tags: c#

So I have a method that I "borrowed" from the internet that I use on many of my pages to handle the sorting of a grid column.

```
        private string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {

        // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
        string sortDirection = "ASC";

        // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            // Check if the same column is being sorted.
            // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }

        // Save new values in ViewState.
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }
```

Now it works great, but alas, I must copy it to every page that I want to call it from because it references the viewstate.  So I want to move it to my helper class and have it store in the session state instead, however, I can referernce neither State in the helper class.

Is their any way to access the session from a help class?  Can I pass by reference the session state?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're looking to access `ViewState` or `Session` from a class that is not a page.

If so, you can use `HttpContext.Current.Session`, or, you should be able to typecast `HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler` to type `Page`, and then access the `ViewState`.

Alternatively, you could always just put your code in a base class, which all your pages will inherit from, rather than inheriting from `System.Web.UI.Page`.

Comment: I looked into your idea of making a base class and it was just  so simple and easy!

Answer (score 1):

No you don't use Session, because if you test Session, you have user 1 that select One Columns 1, and he changes page, he will have the same selected columns, this is problem , becaue when use initilize page, he must have initial state and no selected state.

Technically you can use Session but for me functionaly it's not recomended

Comment: I don't need to store it in the session, my real consern is to get rid of all my duplicate methods.

Comment: You can also create BasePage and in your page inherit from this, you set your common method in this class

Answer (score 1):

You can use `HttpContext.Current.Session` in any assembly which references System.Web and is executing in a web process.

However, putting generic (i.e. reused in multiple places, non-specific key) values like that in Session will cause all sorts of trouble. For example, what if the user opens two browser windows in the same session?

I would suggest either a base `Page`/`Control`/`UserControl` class, or a helper class which is initialized with data from the page. Your code sample looks more like it belongs in control-related base class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use System.Web.HttpContext.Current however you could run into some syncing issues using session state like this. It's possible you could add your GetSortDirection method as an extension method to page which may be easier to accomplish.

Comment: I am new to asp.net, So i am uncertain how to do an extension method.  Guess i got some digging to do.